# How do I handle varying work intensity?

Tags: workplace-rhythm

Most of the time at my workplace, I work on projects that are on tight dead lines, stressed customers and a decent pace. I feel comfortable in these environements.

However, some times work pace slows down and even stops (which is natural I guess). My problem with slow downs is that I feel very awkward about the situation. Let's for the sake of simplicity say that I cannot really start innovation/enhancement projects on my own to keep busy (which would have been nice if it was possible).

How can I adapt to such "slow pace" periods quickly (before starting to climb the walls and annoy people)?

Comment: By spending more time on stack exchange.

Comment: But really, this is a very similar question minus the industry-specific stuff: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10645/how-to-keep-busy-during-slow-times-without-looking-like-i-have-nothing-to-do

Comment: @MrFox Ya, SE, of course. Read that question some time ago but it's more about looking busy when you are not. Given there is nothing beside to do (i.e. no cleaning, no process improvements or so that was suggested by that Q ). My question is more on how to ramp down the pace and adjust to a slow pace rathen than finding things to do.

Comment: Are you working as a developer?

Comment: @MichaelZedeler OP is a Integration Architect/Consultant

Comment: @Michael Zedeler: Sort of.. architect/developer-ish. Does it matter for question at hand, how to quickly slow down pace at a workplace?

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that you're working within IT as @Michael Grubey wrote.

In that case, I've always claimed that working with software falls into three categories:

- Analyzing, designing, writing and maintaining code.
- Analyzing, designing, writing and maintaining tools that enhance the above.
- Researching and seeking out new knowledge within IT (which enhances the two above).

Maybe you are not working on anything that fits the first bullet, but switching to any of the other two will just make you better at what you do, and thus more ready to tackle the next deadline. So you can't really be blamed that any such thing is a pet project - even if (when) you (hopefully) find it fun.

Comment: Is it an advantage to be more ready to tackle the next deadline if having no work is something that the OP finds hard to handle?

Comment: My point is that there is never "no work".

Comment: Especially after a busy project, there must be a backlog of things that needed to make way for the high priority project.